# AutoHotKey - Open a website without giving it focus

Tags: autohotkey

I just created this script, and it is nearly perfect (for my needs). The only thing I would love to be able to do to improve it is make it so when it runs Google.com, it does not give my Google Chrome focus. How can this be done?

```
#PgDn::
Run https://www.google.com
Sleep 2000
SetControlDelay -1
ControlClick, x1570 y600, Google - Google Chrome,,,, NA
Return
```

Essentially, when I press Windows key + Page Down, it runs google chrome (and gives it focus) then waits two seconds and control clicks a coordinate on the page (does not move my mouse). I would love for this whole operation to be done without Google getting focus or my mouse moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably going to want to wait for it to get focus and then just immediately restore it back to whatever had focus. If this is not good enough, I'd imagine you'd need some custom Chrome extension to do this.

To restore focus after Chrome steals it, you can do this:

```
SetControlDelay -1

#PgDn::
    ActiveWindow := WinActive("A") ;store the hwnd of current active window
    Run, https://www.google.com
    WinWaitActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe ;wait for chrome to get focus
    WinActivate, % "ahk_id " ActiveWindow ;restore focus
    ControlClick, x1570 y600, Google - Google Chrome, , , , NA
Return
```

Also moved `SetControlDelay -1` to be set outside of the hotkey.
There's no need to set it every time you run the hotkey, just it set it once in your script's [auto-execute section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto) (top of your script).